# Problem with nesting environments

Tags: environments, nesting

I have a problem with nesting environments. I have created a MWE for this.
I have environment {env1} which I want to contain environments {env2} and {env3} in the following way. What's wrong with the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{env1}{}{}
\newenvironment{env2}{}{}
\newenvironment{env3}{}{}

\newenvironment{test1}%
{\begin{env1} \begin{env2}}%
{\end{env2}}

\newenvironment{test2}%
{\begin{env3}}%
{\end{env3} \end{env1}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{test1}
        This is test1
    \end{test1}

    \begin{test2}
        This is test2
    \end{test2}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

It seems that in order to solve this problem I need to give the details of my lengthy code... (wanted to avoid it because of the length) So here it is:
I tried to apply Patrick's patch, as it looked closest to what I wanted. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

In my code,
env1=block, env2=exercise*, env3=solution*, test1=exercise, test2=solution. The "exercise" and "solution" macros are designed to ease writing when the block of exercises consists of only 1 exercise and 1 solution, and it automatically build the block around the exercise* and solution*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\thickline}{\noindent\textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{5pt}}}

\newenvironment{block}
{\bigskip\par\thickline\nopagebreak\par%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent\relax}\small}
{\end{minipage}\par\smallskip\nopagebreak\thickline\bigskip}

\newenvironment{exercise*}[1]
{\medskip\smallskip\par\noindent\textbf{Exercise (#1):}}
{\bigskip}

\newenvironment{solution*}
{\par\noindent\textbf{Solution:}}
{\medskip\smallskip}

%***Patrick's solution:*** (doesn't seem to work, see below)
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]%
    {\csname block\endcsname \begin{exercise*}{#1}}%
    {\end{exercise*}}

\newenvironment{solution}%
{\begin{solution*}}%
{\end{solution*} \csname endblock\endcsname}
%**************

\begin{document}
%This works. (using the 3 environments)
    \begin{block}
        \begin{exercise*}{hmmm}
            First exercise
        \end{exercise*}

        \begin{solution*}
            First Solution
        \end{solution*}
    \end{block}

    %This doesn't work (Patrick's definitions with csname):
    \begin{exercise}{hmmm}
        exercise
    \end{exercise}

    \begin{solution}
        solution
    \end{solution}
    %************

\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**

In case the block consists of more than one exercise, I want them to be separated by a thin line, defined by

```
\newcommand{\thinline}{\noindent\textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}}
```

and the thick lines would come at the beginning and end of the block.
So if there are 2 exercises in the block, for example, it would look like:

\thickline

**Exercise (First exercise):**

This is exercise 1

**Solution:**

Solution 1

\thinline

**Exercise (Second exercise):**

This is exercise 2

**Solution:**

Solution 2

\thickline

Comment: For starters you have some typos: 'evn1' instead of 'env1'.

Comment: Was that the critical part?

Comment: A remark: the `\csname` .. `\endcsname` is only necessary because of the number in the command name. With the environment `block` you can write just `block` and `\endblock`. It has no influence on nesting / your problem.

Comment: @Patrick: Oh, ok. I didn't know that

Answer (score 7):

Your `test1` and `test2` environments must be used one after the other, so probably another strategy is better:

```
\newenvironment{test}
  {\begin{env1}\begin{env2}}
  {\end{env3}\end{env1}}

\newcommand{\testbreak}[1]{\end{env2}#1\begin{env3}}

\begin{test}
Contents for env2
\testbreak{...}
Contents for env3
\end{test}
```

Possible text to be set between `env2` and `env3` can be specified as argument to `\testbreak`, with a suitable definition.

EDIT:

With your example at hand, the proposal is

```
\newif\ifsolution
\newenvironment{exercise}[1]
  {\begin{block}\begin{exercise*}{#1}}
  {\ifsolution\end{solution*}\else\end{exercise*}\fi\end{block}}
\newcommand\solution{\end{exercise*}\solutiontrue\begin{solution*}}
```

Exercises can then be typeset in the `exercise` environment, where `\solution` (which may not be present) will start the solution.

```
\begin{exercise}{difficult}
  exercise
\solution
  solution
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}{easy}
exercise
\end{exercise}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to keep the 3 entities as environments. See the edit in my message

Comment: @Andro See edited answer

Comment: Thanks. That looks good! I also want to know if it can automatically implement a functionality I wanted to use (I planned to do it manually, but if automatism is possible I would prefer it). See my edited message

Comment: @Andro Define a `\newexercise` macro, along the lines of `\solution`; you'll need a new conditional.

Answer (score 3):

This is not recommended, I assume, as it does no proper environment initialization/checking. Some LaTeX experts could explain what is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{env1}{(begin env1)}{(end env1)}
\newenvironment{env2}{(begin env2)}{(end env2)}
\newenvironment{env3}{(begin env3)}{(end env3)}

\newenvironment{test1}%
{\csname env1\endcsname \begin{env2}}%
{\end{env2}}

\newenvironment{test2}%
{\begin{env3}}%
{\end{env3} \csname endenv1\endcsname}


\begin{document}

    \begin{test1}
        This is test1
    \end{test1}

    \begin{test2}
        This is test2
    \end{test2}

\end{document}
```

The `\csname env1\endcsname` construct builds a control sequence `\env1` where 1 is part of the macro name. When you've got numbers in a macro name, you have to make special arrangements  to create a macro name.

Comment: Nice touch, but I still don't see how `env1` and `endenv1` relate to each other. What I see here is still nesting in the most traditional sense.

Comment: @CountZero I just want to solve the problem. If Andro had provided more information I could have written something about whether this approach solves his problem or not. There is nothing special I want to show. (Or perhaps I don't get your comment right.)

Comment: @Patrick thanks, I tried to apply it but it doesn't seem to work. See the edit in my message, with details of my actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest environments that way. An environment has to have a `\begin{env-name}` and an `\end{env-name}` statement. You broke that rule when you separated the beginning and end of `env1` across `test1` and `test2`. This is not permitted, because by defining `test1` and `test2` you define two new scopes. Once you use an environment inside them, you also have to finish them *within the same* scope. This is a basic programming rule; unfortunately for you it's impossible to break an environment up like that.

Comment: Basic programming rules applying to TeX? I wish this could be true.

Comment: @Patrick: And why wouldn't that be true? Where do you start a procedure/function/environment/etc. without closing it?

Comment: Is there a way around this, maybe with an appropriate package, or organizing it differently? My goal was to create a macro that automatically "appends" env1 as the container without writing it explicitly every time.

Comment: @CountZero you can use e.g. `\begingroup` in one definition and `\endgroup` in another definition. I don't think TeX's programming language can be compared to any other well known language.

Comment: How could one nest `align` environment within `tabular` environment?