# Aligning plain `align` and `cases`?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, cases

The `cases` environment works very well for enumerating cases within a large left bracket. I'd like to be able to combine it with the `align` environment so that equals-signs and conditions also line up:

```
\item \begin{align*}
T_{in\ general}\left(n\right)&=aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + n^{c},\   &a\geq1, b\geq1, c>0
 \end{align*}

\[T_{cases}\left(n\right)= 
   \begin{cases}
   \Theta\left(n^{\log_{b}a}\right) &a>b^{c}\\
   \Theta\left(n^{c}\log_{b}n\right) &a=b^{c}\\
   \Theta\left(n^{c}\right) &a<b^{c}
   \end{cases}\]
```

Separate `align` and `case` environments do not share alignments:

[image]

Is there a reasonably simple way to get (say) the leftmost equals-signs in the two equations here to line up, and separately from them the conditions ("a…")?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is fairly elementary to align both equations, as well as their variable domains, when defining your own "`cases` environment" via an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  T_{\text{in general}}\left(n\right) &= aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + n^{c}, && a\geq 1, b\geq 1, c>0 \\
  & && a>b^{c} \\
  T_{\text{cases}}\left(n\right) &= 
    \smash{\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
      \Theta\left(n^{\log_{b}a}\right) \\[\jot]
      \Theta\left(n^{c}\log_{b}n\right) \\[\jot]
      \Theta\left(n^{c}\right)
    \end{array}\right.} && a=b^{c} \\
  & && a<b^{c}
\end{align*}
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Some minor alignment adjustments were made (like using additional `&` alignment specifiers), as well as `\smash`ing the "`cases` environment" and adding the `[\jot]` line skip. `\smash` removed any vertical height from it's argument, while `\jot` is a specific `3pt` skip provided by LaTeX.

From a typesetting point of view, note the use of `\text{...}` in the subscripts. This macro is offered by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and allows text to be typeset in the regular way, while still adjusting for the relative size of the font depending on the placement.

Answer (score 10):

With careful use of the `\phantom` family of commands, you can get proper alignment inside and outside of the `cases` (i.e., the second portion of your equation) as well:

[image]

This is a general solution that I often use and will work across different environment as well. We fix a size for portions of the equations, and use `\makebox` to set that text in the specified fixed width.  You can specify this fixed width as in:

```
\newcommand{\FixedSize}[1]{\makebox[1.5in][l]{\ensuremath{#1}}}%
```

This allows you to easily adjust this width to get the display that you want for the appropriate portions of the equation.

A better solution is to automatically compute the required width using [the `calc` package's](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) `\widthof` command.  For this we select what is the widest portion that we need to be able to accomodate and then compute the width of that. You can do this all in one line, but for readability I have defined `\WidestPart` separately, and used it to compute the width.

One slight complication in this specific situation is the left brace from the `cases`. To adjust for this I defined `\PhantomBrace` which produces a horizontal space equivalent to the width of the brace used for a three line cases, and include that in the adjustment of the first equation.

I added a `\quad` to separate these two portions but any value can be used here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\WidestPart}{\ensuremath{aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + n^{c},}}%
\newcommand{\FixedSize}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{\WidestPart}][l]{\ensuremath{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\PhantomBrace}{\hphantom{\left\{\vphantom{\begin{cases}\\\\\end{cases}}\right.}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
T_{in\ general}\left(n\right)&=\FixedSize{aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + n^{c},}\PhantomBrace\qquad a\geq1, b\geq1, c>0\\
T_{cases}\left(n\right) &= 
   \begin{cases}
   \FixedSize{\Theta\left(n^{\log_{b}a}\right)}  \qquad a>b^{c}\\
   \FixedSize{\Theta\left(n^{c}\log_{b}n\right)} \qquad a=b^{c}\\
   \FixedSize{\Theta\left(n^{c}\right)}          \qquad a<b^{c}
   \end{cases}
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks; the detail in this discussion was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 8):

You can combine the two equations into one single `align` environment, i.e. nest the `cases` inside the `align` environment:

```
\begin{align*}
T_{in\ general}\left(n\right)&=aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) + n^{c},\ &a\geq1, b\geq1, c>0\\
T_{cases}\left(n\right)&= 
\begin{cases}
\Theta\left(n^{\log_{b}a}\right) &a>b^{c}\\
\Theta\left(n^{c}\log_{b}n\right) &a=b^{c}\\
\Theta\left(n^{c}\right) &a<b^{c}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
```

and the result will be:

[image]

**EDIT:** If you remove the `&` in the first equation before `a\geq1, b\geq1, c>0\\` and replace it with `\hspace{0.4cm}` you should get the desired result of having the conditions also lined up properly. If you have different quations, obviously you will have to modify the amount of horizontal space.

I guess the explanation why you need this workaround is that the ampersads inside the `case` environment go out of scope when you return to the `align` environment proper and will not interact with those contained in the latter.

Comment: Okay, how about the "a\geq1" and "a>b^c" conditions at right? The ampersands within the `cases` environment don't seem to be aware of the second ampersand in the first line.

Comment: @brannerchinese: Not possible.  The `cases` alignment is totally separate from its surroundings.

Comment: @brannerchinese: I've heard that in (La)TeX it is possible to mix two environments, say you open `env1`, open `env2`, close `env1` while inside `env2` and finally close `env2`. I'm quite skeptical that works, and if it does, I think it's bad practice, beside being a stunt from the trickback of a TeX voodoo grandmaster. :)

Comment: @CountZero: You heard wrong, then.  If you try this, you will get an error "\begin{env2} ended on line ? by \end{env1}".

Comment: @RyanReich: This is not just about nesting the usual way and I don't know what it really does: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30661/problem-with-nesting-environments/30670#30670](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30661/problem-with-nesting-environments/30670#30670) I'm not sure it works at all.

Comment: @CountZero: But that doesn't do what you described: it defines a pair of environments where the first "opens" env1 and then opens env2, and when closed then closes env2; the second then opens some other env3 and closes it, and finally "closes" env1.  The quotes are because it skips the `\begin` and `\end` parts that do the checking that give the error I described.  This does not, however, close an outer environment while inside a nested one, which seems to be what you were saying.

Comment: @RyanReich: I told you I can't imagine such thing happening myself, so better ask Patrick himself. Imho it's contrary to the basic principles of proper programming.

Comment: @CountZero: Regardless, that won't work here.  The alignment environments are based around TeX's primitive `\halign`, and it is not possible to mix and match the contents of those commands.  Even if in some special situation you can coerce LaTeX into interleaving environments, the environments have to be specially designed to work together, which these are not.

Comment: @CountZero: Thanks, colleagues. Although this appears not to be the solution most convenient for me, I'm grateful for the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use manual adjustments (in plain-tex):

```
\def\mathcolstyle{\mathsurround0pt\mathstrut\displaystyle}% re-usable style def.
\def\quadcol#1{$\vcenter{\openup-1\jot\halign{% negate the \jot from \mymathalign
  \quad$\mathcolstyle{}##\hfil$\crcr#1\crcr}}$}
\def\mymathalign#1{\vcenter{\openup1\jot\halign{$\hfil\mathcolstyle{}##$&
  $\mathcolstyle{}{}##\hfil$&
  ##\crcr#1\crcr}}}
$$
  \mymathalign{
    % first row:
    T_{\rm in~general}(n) & % first column
      = aT\Big({n\over b}\Big)+n^c, & % second column
      \quadcol{ a\geq 1, b\geq 1, c > 0 } % third column
    \cr
    % second row:
    T_{\rm cases}(n) & % first column
      = \cases{ % second column
        \Theta(n^{\log_b a}) \cr
        \Theta(n^c \log_b n) \cr
        \Theta(n^c) \cr
      } &
      \quadcol{ % third column
        a > b^c \cr
        a = b^c \cr
        a < b^c \cr
      }
    \cr
    % third row just to show the column boundaries:
    \omit\llap{\smash{\vrule height 15ex}}&
      \omit\llap{\smash{\vrule height 15ex}}&
      \omit\llap{\smash{\vrule height 15ex}}\cr
  }
$$
\bye
```

Looks like:
[image]

Basically the second column from the `\cases` has to be set outside of it, inside another `\halign` (or other construct), to be able to get them to line up.

Comment: I should also note that I don't find anything "elementary" about these...