# Horizontal alignment with align and cases

Tags: align, cases

I have a `cases` environment inside an `align` environment, and I'm trying to align part of one line of the `align` environment with part of the `cases` environment via an ugly `\phantom` command.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\mathrlap{2}\phantom{\begin{cases}1&\\0&\end{cases}}\text{if }x>0\\
g(x)&=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the 'if's to be horizontally aligned, and I don't understand why they're not - maybe something to do with the spacing that LaTeX puts around a `cases` environment.

Can anyone see a fix (other than just doing it 'by hand' with `\vspace`)?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33377/27635 for a better solution

Comment: BTW: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're forgetting the `\nulldelimiterspace` that's added when a null delimiter is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\mathrlap{2}
  \hphantom{\begin{cases}1&\\0&\end{cases}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \text{if }x>0\\
g(x)&=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x>0\\0&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

You should use `\hphantom` rather than `\phantom`, so the vertical size is not taken into account.

[image]